# How to implement single sign on using SML2.0 in RightNow frame work?

Tags: saml-2.0, rightnow-crm

How to implement single sign on by using SML2.0 in RightNow frame work?

Comment: You'll need to narrow down the details of your question. It's too broad. You'll need a IdP and then RightNow can / will act as the SP... Beyond that, too much of a topic.

Answer (score 3):

If by framework, you mean the RightNow Connect APIs, they do not currently support SAML 2.0 authentication, this is something that will be coming in a future release.

If you are looking to use SAML tokens for SSO with the agent desktop, or the Customer Portal, you can find some additional information here:
[RightNow Single Sign-On](https://cx.rightnow.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4288)

Answer (score 1):

RightNow has supported a flavor of SAML 2.0 since the May 2011 Release (11.5). It is impossible to debug, difficult to set-up and you are required to use a SAML setup with an unsolicited assertion via POST bindings from the Identity Provider to RightNow, but it does work once everything is aligned.

By unsolicited assertion, I mean than you can't try to access RightNow and be automatically directed to your Identity Provider. You have to start at the Identity Provider and request access to RightNow (Service Provider) from some sort of dashboard or direct access URL (depends on your Identity Provider).

My latest experience was setting up SSO with the Oracle suite of OIM/OAAM/OAM/OIM with the February 2013 version. It was a pain, but we got it working.

Also, the latest release of RightNow (November 2013, 13.11) has the ability to use RightNow as an Identity Provider.

Comment: Link to the latest versions docs for Agent SSO via SAML:
[https://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/docs/november2013/olh/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=crm&file=crm_admin_saml_sso.19.2.html](https://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/docs/november2013/olh/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=crm&file=crm_admin_saml_sso.19.2.html)